# Sybase - Setting console output on for printing log statements

Tags: sql, printing, console, sybase, output

Does somebody know how to turn the console output on in Sybase. The usual statement like  `print 'Hello'`, is not working for me, it just says command executed successfully without printing the log statement.

Comment: Hi, I found this question while looking for a solution to a similar problem. I'm using the Sybase Interactive SQL tool and in order to print messages, I had to replace `print 'foo bar'` with `message 'foo bar' type status to client`. I don't know if this is what you were asking so I'm posting as a comment.

Answer (score 3):

Are you using Interactive SQL in sybase? Or are you invoking dbisqlc with -nogui option and passing it an SQL file for it to run?

The 'message' method is only for interactive mode.

I'm trying to figure this out as well, but as far as I can tell the console output doesn't seem to work. I tried using 'select' statement such as:

```
SELECT "This is my message";
```

And it seems to work, but is a little too hacky for my tastes.

Please let me know if this works/you figured something better out :)

~Will

Comment: If you are trying this hack, switch to single quotes as double doesn't work.

Comment: Unfortunately `dbisql` seems to ignore anything else after the first statement in each file, so this does not really work this way.

Comment: I have to clarify my last comment: it is possible, but you must first set `dbisql` to return all result sets with `SET OPTION ISQL_PRINT_RESULT_SET='ALL';` as seen on https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/SQLANY/How+to+Configure+Interactive+SQL+to+Return+Multiple+Result+Sets (default is `LAST`). Then it works as you described.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your setup. If you are using SQL Anywhere, `PRINT 'Hello'` will **not** be written to the client window if you are [connected from an embedded SQL or ODBC application](http://dcx.sap.com/1200/en/dbreference/print-statement.html). The printed message will however be visible in the [Server Messages in Sybase Central](http://dcx.sybase.com/1200/en/dbadmin/logsqlstatements-sc.html).

In your case, you'll probably need `MESSAGE 'Hello' type status to client` as @toniedzwiedz mentioned.

Answer (score -1):

```
DECLARE @var1 INT, @var2 INT
SELECT @var1 = 3, @var2 = 5
PRINT 'Variable 1 = %1!, Variable 2 = %2!', @var1, @var2
```

Comment: Isn't it the same as `print 'Hello'` which isn't working for OP?